# htaccess return json from folder root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

#### How can I return an `index.json` file in a folder when the folder is navigated to using .htaccess?

I have the following directory and file structure:

```
/api/.htaccess
/api/index.json
/api/page-1/index.json
/api/page-1/page-a/index.json
/api/page-1/page-b/index.json
/api/page-2/index.json
/api/page-2/page-a/index.json
/api/page-2/page-b/index.json
/api/page-foo/index.json
```

and I would like them to appear when you navigate to the following URLs:

```
/api/
/api/page-1/
/api/page-1/page-a/
/api/page-1/page-b/
/api/page-2/
/api/page-2/page-a/
/api/page-2/page-b/
/api/page-foo/
```

How can I update the `api/.htaccess` file to allow this? So far all I have working is this bit:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.json [L]
AddType application/json json
```

Which is successfully showing `/api/index.json` at the `/api/` endpoint, but it doesn't point `/api/page-1/` to `/api/page-1/index.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a rule for this. Just use [`DirectoryIndex`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex):

```
DirectoryIndex index.json
```

Comment: You can remove `RewriteRule ^/?$ index.json [L]` rule as well after this directive.